# Store Null value in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I have a row with *`nullable` columns* in my table in **SQL Server**. I tried to store values like this.

```
if (chkQCE3AS1.Checked)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QCEA1S1", selectedID);
else
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QCEA1S1", "");
```

But that would store a space in the column. What would be another way to store a `null` value? Or is it even a good idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) that will do your task.

```
        if (chkQCE3AS1.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QCEA1S1", selectedID);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QCEA1S1", DBNull.Value);
```